# Angular - how handle click event inside other clickable container

Tags: angular, events, onclick

I have a clickable div which on click navigates to other page. Inside this div I'd like to have a like-component. If user clicks the like then onLikeClicked() should be executed but onContainerClick() should be blocked. Clicking somewhere else inside container should execute onContainerClick(). How can I block onContainerClick() event if user clicks directly on like component?

```
<div class="container" (click)="onContainerClick()">
    <like (click)="onLikeClicked()">
        
    </like>
</div>
```

Comment: You can just use the css property `z-index`. If you're doing <like style="z-index: 1" (click)="onLikeClicked()">"` it will work. The method on like component will be called and not the container method (it will not be blocked but never called)

Comment: I like the z-index method better than passing the event and stopping propagation, as it tackles it at the HTML (well, OK, CSS) level rather than requiring TS code. @Lud, this should be an answer in itself

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can stop the propogation of the event by using `event.stopPropagation();`

pass the $event to `onLikeClicked` like this:

```
    <like (click)="onLikeClicked($event)">
    </like>
```

then in the function you can call `event.stopPropagation();`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Answer (score 7):

You could call the [`stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) function in the `like` element's click event to stop the event bubbling.

Try the following

Controller

```js
export class AppComponent  {
  onContainerClick(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();           // <-- also if you want to stop container click event bubbling
    console.log("container clicked");
  }

  onLikeClicked(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log('like clicked');
  }
}
```

Template

```html
<div (click)="onContainerClick($event)" class="container">
  <p (click)="onLikeClicked($event)" class="content">Something inside</p>
</div>
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dr49sl?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 4):

You have to stop the event propagation. This not angular specific, just basic javascript. As the official documentation for `stopImmediatePropagation()` states:

> Invoking this method prevents event from reaching any registered event listeners after the current one finishes running and, when dispatched in a tree, also prevents event from reaching any other objects.

**component.html**

```html
<div class="container" (click)="onContainerClick()">
    <like (click)="onLikeClicked($event)">
        
    </like>
</div>
```

**component.ts**

```js
export class Component {

  onContainerClick(): void {
    // do something
  }

  onLikeClicked(event: MouseEvent): void {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    // do something
  }
}
```